Google vison response access changes in different system(using python)
I am using google vision api for text annotations but,
why in some systems, the system accepts this response.full_text_annotation.pages of google vison, and in some systems it accepts  this response["fullTextAnnotation"]["pages"] of google vison. Why is it so?, because of it i have to change the code again and again just to itterate inside the response, in different systems.
for page in response["fullTextAnnotation"]["pages"]:
  for block in page["blocks"]:
     for paragraph in block["paragraphs"]:
        for word in paragraph["words"]:
           print(word)


->but in some sytem the method it allows to itterate is 

for text in response.full_text_annotation.pages:
   for block in text.blocks:
       for para in block.paragraphs:
          for word in para.words:
             print(word)

